# installed debian in a multi hard disks environment but when I restart I get "operating system missing" message

Tags: debian, debian-installer, mbr

I have 4 hard disks installed:

- ssd with windows;
- hd with other stuffs;
- **hd 1TB where I installed debian**;
- hd with windows home.

I installed debian in the third hd, creating 3 partitions inside it:

- 38gb with / as mounting point and bootable;
- 16gb of swap partition;
- about 945gb with /home as mounting point.

The installation is worked fine, and in the end the system asked to install MBR in the first hard disk (where there is windows).
I answered "No" and I installed MBR in the third hard disk (the next install screen asked for that).

I rebooted the system and I choose the third hd as booting hd, but I get the message "operating system missing".

Comment: Is Windows in UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR? If system is UEFI, then you may get that error. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I am pretty sure win is in bios/mbr.

Comment: "Pretty sure" is why we ask for Summary report. Then we know your configuration.